# Microsoft Graph problem when uploading a file to sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error cuando trato de subir ficheros a sharepoint usando la API Graph:

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
Unknown location
TaskCanceledException: Upload failed too many times. See InnerException for list of exceptions that occured.
Microsoft.Graph.LargeFileUploadTask.UploadAsync(IProgress progress, int maxTries)*

```
         using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {


                    // Use properties to specify the conflict behavior
                    // in this case, replace
                    var uploadProps = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
                    {
                        ODataType = null,
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" }
                            }
                    };


                    var uploadSession = await _graphServiceClient.Drives["b!G_sdavHlaEmqc9oVvd2b-WJ1ylhoxrtPt9v6xJPy1RQH5vGZK44uQau0-P9QCo5r"]
                       .Root
                       .ItemWithPath(file.FileName)
                       .CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
                       .Request()
                       .PostAsync();

                    // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
                    int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
                    var fileUploadTask =
                        new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);

                 

                    // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
                    IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {fileStream.Length} bytes");
                    });

                    try
                    {
                        // Upload the file
                         
                       var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

                        if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
                        {
                            // The ItemResponse object in the result represents the
                            // created item.
                            Console.WriteLine($"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Upload failed");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ServiceException ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
                    }

                  
                }
```

Este es el código que estoy usando (El DriveID y el ItemId existen en Sharepoint, de hecho los obtengo de el, por lo tanto por aquí no va el problema)

El programa da el error, pero si accedemos a Sharepoint podemos ver como un fichero temporal se ha creado, por lo tanto, llegar si llega a Sharepoint solo que parece que no se completa la subida.

*
Creaste ~tmp95_Manipulador de Alimentos GUERO...pdf en ex3
Hace un minuto*

¿Alguna pista sobre donde puede estar el problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hi. spanish is the official language for this site. please translate the question, if not it could be close.

Comment: Es necesario que uses un `UploadSession` para subir el archivo? Para documentos que no pesen mas de 4MB puedes usar la subida directa de archivos